# How effectively split line?

Tags: tcl

I would like to split line by    `\t`    `=`    or `,`

I have try to use:

```
set line [split $line" \t=,"]
set result {}
foreach element $line {
    if { $element != {} } { 
        lappend result $element
    }
}
```

Lines look like:

```
name1 name2 name3 floating_point_number1, floating_point_number2
```

or

```
name = floating_point_number1, floating_point_number2 ... floating_point_numbern-1, floating_point_numbern
```

But it's seem very slow.
How can I change the code to be more effective?

Comment: Please show some sample input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the [`textutil::split`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html) module from tcllib.

```
% set s "this\tis=a,line=,\twith separators="
this    is=a,line=, with separators=
% package require textutil::split
0.7
% textutil::split::splitx $s {[[:blank:]=,]}
this is a line {} {} {with separators} {}
```

If it's the empty elements you want to avoid, then the tcllib [`struct::list`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.html) package helps

```
% package req struct::list
1.7
% set l [textutil::split::splitx $s {[[:blank:]=,]}]
this is a line {} {} {with separators} {}
% struct::list filterfor field $l {[llength $field] > 0}
this is a line {with separators}
```

Comment: changed `\t` to `[:blank:]` to match any horizontal whitespace.